# ¿Cómo poner en rojo la validación de JQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Quisiera poner en rojo el mensaje que sale en la validación usando `JQuery Validate`

Formulario

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Registro de Direccionamientos</h2>
                </div>

                <form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="blMaster">BL MASTER</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blMaster" id="blMaster" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/direccionamiento.js"></script>

</body>
```

funcionalida JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    direccionamiento.init();
    direccionamiento.init_botones();
});

var direccionamiento = function() {
    return {

        init: function() {
            $(".divCapacidad").hide();
        },
        init_botones: function() {
            $("#btnRegistrar").click(function() {
                direccionamiento.validar();
            });
        },

        funcionReefer: function(item) {

            if (item == "reefer") {
                $(".divCapacidad").show();
            } else {
                $(".divCapacidad").hide();
            }
        },

        validar: function() {
            var formDireccionamiento = $("#defaultForm");
            formDireccionamiento.validate({
                rules: {
                    blMaster: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    blMaster: {
                        required: "El campo es requerido"
                    }
                }
            }).form();

            if (formDireccionamiento.valid()) {
                alert("funciona");
            }
        }
    }
}();
```